# Files empty after download

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, blob

I'm trying to download files of different types in a database's `blob` column.
When I open files and images, all the files are empty.
What's going wrong?

```
$file = DB::table('files')->where('id', $fileId)->get()[0];

header("Content-length: $file->file_size");
header("Content-type: $file->file_type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file->file_name");
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $file->file;
```

Answer (score 1):

use the ready to use laravel response for file donwload

```
$file = DB::table('files')->where('id', $fileId)->get()[0];
return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($file) {
    echo $file->file;
}, $file->file_name);
```

Comment: also empty file

Comment: This still returns an empty file for me.

Comment: @Carol-TheodorPelu do you have the content of the file in the BLOB field "File" of your table ?

Comment: My file is a base64 encoded string. Tried to download it both encoded and decoded and didn't work.

Comment: I managed to make it to work.
            $headers = [
                "Content-type" => "application/octet-stream",
                'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . 'test.jpg' . ';',
                "Pragma" => "no-cache",
                "Expires" => "0",
                "Content-Length" => strlen(base64_decode($file))
            ];

            return response()->streamDownload(function() use ($file) {
                echo base64_decode($file);
            }, 'test.jpg', $headers);

Comment: @Carol-TheodorPelu the only thing you had to change was `echo base64_decode($file)` since you saved the content in a TEXT field with an encoded value in Base64 and not a BLOB field.